# Scala, Cake Pattern, and MacWire

Tags: scala, dependency-injection

I've implemented an Email service using the cake pattern. Here below is the `EmailComponent`, which provides functionality for styling the email body:

```
trait EmailComponent {
  def body: Body

  trait Body {
    def style(content Html): Html
  }
}

trait DefaultEmailComponent extends EmailComponent {
  def body = new DefaultBody

  class DefaultBody extends Body {
    views.html.email(content)
  }
}
```

... and here is the `EmailServiceComponent` that actually implements the Email service using an `EmailComponent`:

```
trait EmailServiceComponent {
  def emailService: EmailService

  trait EmailService {
    def sendEmail(from: String, recipients: Seq[String], subject: String, content: Html)
  }
}

trait DefaultEmailServiceComponent extends EmailServiceComponent {
  this: EmailComponent =>

  def emailService = new DefaultEmailService

  class DefaultEmailService extends EmailService {
    def sendEmail(from: String, recipients: Seq[String], subject: String, content: Html) {
      val htmlBody = body.style(content)
      EmailHelper.sendEmail(from, recipients, Some(subject), (None, Some(htmlBody)))
    }
  }
```

The code above works fine... but I was surfing on the Internet when I came across MacWire. I read some documentation here and there and found really interesting, but to be honest I haven't fully understood how to use it and how it works. Having said that, how could I reimplement the example above with MacWire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several things to consider:

1. One big difference is that the cake pattern in your example uses inheritance / class composition to satisfy dependencies and build the concrete instances, whereas with dependency injection you would mostly use delegation. It's up to you to decide how tightly coupled you want the classes to be.
2. There are limitations in MacWire to wiring when using traits defined
   inside other traits. So your `Default...` implementations would have to
   go outside of their parent traits.
3. Upon a quick glance, it appears that MacWire cannot resolve concrete
   implementations of a trait (unlike Guice, a well-established
   dependency-injection framework for Java, where you could use
   bindings and annotations for that). This means you'd have to use `wire[DefaultEmailService]` instead of `wire[EmailService]`.
4. There is no support for circular dependencies in MacWire. In the case above, you don't have them anyway: EmailServiceComponent depends on EmailService which in turn depends on EmailComponent.

So, with MacWire, your code would just be classes that use other classes, like

```
class DefaultEmailComponent extends EmailComponent { ... }
class DefaultEmailService(emailComponent: EmailComponent) extends EmailService { ... }
trait EmailServiceComponent {
    def emailService: EmailService
}
class DefaultEmailServiceComponent(val emailService: EmailService) 
                                              extends EmailServiceComponent { ... }

lazy val emailC: EmailComponent = wire[DefaultEmailComponent]
lazy val emailSvc: EmailService = wire[DefaultEmailService]
lazy val emailSvcC: EmailServiceComponent = wire[DefaultEmailServiceComponent]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation :-) If I'm not wrong in MacWire lingo 'Component' is 'Module', isn't it?

Comment: according to their wiki, in MacWire modules are any Scala traits, classes or objects

Comment: As for 3., the whole point is that MacWire doesn't have to do any scanning, etc - you simply specify which classes should be used for wiring. So you have to specify at some point, which class to use as an implementation for a specific trait/interface, which is "injected" elsewhere.

Comment: Just in case someone really had to  deal with `circular dependencies `, a `call-by-name` dependency will help